# How to Enable Scroll Bar iside Ant Design Modal Component Body?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I am having a modal with long content. I need to have an internal scroll bar inside the modal but there is no information about that in the documentation

```
 <Modal
        title={<Typography style={{color:'#2e186a'}}>FAQ</Typography>}
        centered
        visible={openFaq}
        onOk={() => setopenFaq(false)}
        onCancel={() => setopenFaq(false)}
        width={1000}
        footer={false}
        
      >
       {Content}
      </Modal>
```

Any help is welcome.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to provide the maxHeight option inside **bodyStyle** prop along with
**overFlow** set to **auto**

```
<Modal
   bodyStyle={{ overflowY: 'auto', maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 200px)' }}
>
{content}
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 5):

A suggestion by using CSS

```
<Modal
  bodyStyle={{overflowX: 'scroll'}}
>
  {Content}
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this as following:

- Modify `.ant-modal-content` class

```css
.ant-modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

- Add fixed height and `overflowY: scroll` to the Modal

```
<Modal
  style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 200px)' }}
  bodyStyle={{ overflowY: 'scroll' }}
>
  Your content
</Modal>
```

Comment: Height should be under bodyStyle prop instead of style